# Add some custom text after a custom field on single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom field named "mekos" on my product pages product attributes.
I would like to show some additional custom text, for example "centimeters", after the value is displayed.
[The spot that I want the custom text "centimeters" to be displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1uWN.png)

This is the code I have so far:

```
function yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes($product_attributes, $product){
$mekos = get_post_meta($product->get_ID(), 'mekos', true); 
if( get_field('mekos') ) {
$product_attributes['mekos'] = [
    'label' => 'Μήκος',
    'value' => $mekos ,
]; 
}
return $product_attributes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'yourprefix_woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `if` you have to

```php
if (get_field('mekos')) {
        $product_attributes['mekos'] = [
            'label' => 'Μήκος',
            'value' => $mekos . ' centimeters'
        ]; 
    }
```

Comment: Yes thats it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Always glad to help. I would recommend reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)